# Attempting to compile kernel yields a certification error

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, compiling, kali-linux, grsecurity

I'm currently attempting to follow [Hardening Debian for the Desktop Using Grsecurity](https://micahflee.com/2016/01/debian-grsecurity/) guide in order to install the 4.5.7 kernel with Grsecurity on my Kali Linux desktop.

I am following that list of instructions *verbatim*, except for the fact that I'm trying to use Grsecurity's test patch for the 4.5.7 kernel and I'm running Kali Linux instead of straight Debian.

Every time I attempt to compile the kernel, however, I get this error following the line "CC certs/system_keyring.o":

```
  CC      certs/system_keyring.o
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'debian/certs/benh@debian.org.cert.pem', needed by 'certs/x509_certificate_list'.  Stop.
Makefile:951: recipe for target 'certs' failed
make[1]: *** [certs] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/jc/Downloads/linux-4.5.7'
debian/ruleset/targets/common.mk:295: recipe for target 'debian/stamp/build/kernel' failed
make: *** [debian/stamp/build/kernel] Error 2
```

I get this error, as I found out, for any kernel even if I apply no patches or modifications, so it has something to do with the tools I'm using to compile the kernel (apparently a system keychain of some sort). Can someone out there tell me how to fix my OS and compile my kernel?

P.S. Here is the output of `cat /proc/version`:

```
Linux version 4.6.0-kali1-amd64 (devel@kali.org) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Debian 5.4.0-4) ) #1 SMP Debian 4.6.2-2kali2 (2016-06-28)
```

Comment: Try commenting out the CONFIG_SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS line from your .config ?

Comment: I am confused you say “except for the fact that I'm trying to use Grsecurity's test patch“, and you say “even if I apply no patches". I can not work you what problem you are describing. **Do you get the problem when following the instructions 100%, of is it only when applying the patch?**

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - I get the problem when compiling any kernel in any fashion. I am attempting to compile the kernel the same way as micah lee except for a few differences; but the problem exists whether or I not I try to include grsecurity.

Comment: @Steve, will that affect my final build? I'd rather fix the real problem with my current setup than attempt to remove any essential keys from my new kernel.

Answer (score 59):

I ran into this several years ago on a Debian build. In the `.config` file you copied from `/boot` find and comment out the lines `CONFIG_SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEY`
and `CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_KEY`.

During the build you can use your own cert or just use a random one time cert.

Found the above in this [thread](https://lists.debian.org/debian-kernel/2016/04/msg00579.html).

Comment: For me (4.8) it was CONFIG_SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS

Comment: Oneliner for a 4.19 config - `sed -ri '/CONFIG_SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS/s/=.+/=""/g' .config`

Comment: For me (5.13) I also had to `CONFIG_SYSTEM_REVOCATION_KEYS=""`

Comment: Just to clarify further, what worked for me was commenting out all the three parameters mentioned within the reply and the comments and hit Enter to all the prompts

Answer (score 19):

You can change your config file `.config`

```
CONFIG_SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS="debian/canonical-certs.pem"
```

to

```
CONFIG_SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS=""
```

Comment: This worked for me and super easy

Comment: This is the correct (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/293642/attempting-to-compile-kernel-yields-a-certification-error) for my when compile a Kernel from (https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/compiling-linux-kernel-26.html)

Comment: It can be scripted: `scripts/config -s CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_KEY ''`

Comment: This answer is the official, correct way https://wiki.debian.org/BuildADebianKernelPackage

Answer (score 8):

- In the folder where the kernel source is, create a `debian` folder. Create a `certs` folder in it.
- Create a file named `debian-uefi-certs.pem` with [this content](https://salsa.debian.org/kernel-team/linux/-/blob/master/debian/certs/debian-uefi-certs.pem).

Comment: By "create" do you mean "touch debian-uefi-certs.pem", or do you need to make a file with content? Any specific content?

Comment: yep - touch debian-uefi-certs.pem

Comment: This sounds potentially dangerous.

Comment: Why should they use that particular contents for the file? The link does not seem to end up on an officially endorsed Debian site.

Comment: @Kusalananda The updated site now does.

Answer (score 8):

Ran into this, install the source package through the package manager and move the debian and debian.master folders into the linux source where the makefile is located

```
$ sudo apt search linux-source
# don't worry about it not saying 'generic'

$ sudo apt install linux-source-<version>
$ cd /usr/src/linux-source-<version>
$ sudo tar xf linux-source-<version>.tar.gz
$ sudo mv debian linux-source-<version>/debian
$ sudo mv debian.master linux-source-<version>/debian.master
```

Comment: I did not need to extract an archive, and could just run `cp -r /usr/src/linux-source-5.19.0/debian.master .` and `cp -r /usr/src/linux-source-5.19.0/debian .`

Answer (score 0):

For me, Centos 8, compile 4.19 kernel source.
I disable these:

```
# CONFIG_TRUSTED_KEY
# CONFIG_SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYRING
# CONFIG_SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS=""
```

Then I `make`. It will show some create new cert notice. Then you can continue compile.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I was building a kernel on Rocky using `make oldconfig`

You get `rhel.pem` from the kernel source. On Rocky Linux you can download and unpack the kernel source with the following:

Note: the installs include what is needed to compile the kernel on Rocky minimal.

```bash
# RUN AS ROOT

dnf download --source kernel
rpm2cpio kernel-5.14.0-362.18.1.el9_3.src.rpm | cpio -idmv
tar -xf linux-5.14.0-362.18.1.el9_3.tar.xz

# Sets up the RPM build environment directories under ~/rpmbuild
rpmdev-setuptree

# Installs the source RPM package, which comes with the exact kernel build used to build this version of Rocky
rpm -ivh kernel-5.14.0-362.18.1.el9_3.src.rpm
```

After the rpm command runs the cert will be in `/root/rpmbuild/BUILD/kernel-5.14.0-362.18.1.el9_3/linux-5.14.0-362.18.1.el9.x86_64/certs/rhel.pem`