# Preparing the installer to update Linux kernel in a VirtualBox causes errors connected with CONFIG_X86_X32 and modules.order

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, virtualbox, upgrade, make

I'm trying to update my Linux kernel on VirtualBox from version 5.11.0 to 5.14.21. My distribution is Ubuntu 20.04. I also added a new syscall to the kernel but it seems to be ok.
`$ sudo make localmodconfig` and `$ sudo make` worked out fine, but I'm getting errors when I run `$ sudo make modules_install` to prepare the installer of the kernel.

Here's what I get:

```
max@max-VirtualBox:~/linux-5.14.21$ sudo make modules_install -j4
arch/x86/Makefile:148: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
sed: can't read modules.order: No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:1501: __modinst_pre] Error 2
```

I found a few solutions [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12557096/12787638) and [there](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/646758/502657). But they didn't help.
binutils is installed, I set `CONFIG_X86_X32=n` and `CONFIG_SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS = ""` in `.config`
`$ pwd` returns `/home/max/linux-5.14.21`
Still have the same errors.
Should I run `$ sudo make menuconfig` instead of `$ sudo make localmodconfig`? Or the problem is hidden somewhere in another place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I continued trying to solve the problem after I published this question, and I succeed.

These commands fixed the second error. Found them [there](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1362455/i-am-installing-kernel-in-my-ubuntu-but-getting-an-error) while was going through a series of other errors.

```
$ scripts/config --disable SYSTEM_REVOCATION_KEYS
$ scripts/config --disable SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS
$ sudo make
```

This command fixed the first error.

```
$ sudo make modules
```